# Rspec Custom view testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

This is my rspec for view

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "expense_notifies/index", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:expense_notifies, [
      ExpenseNotify.create!(:user_id => 1),
      ExpenseNotify.create!(:user_id => 2)
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of expense_notifies" do
    render
  end
end
```

This is the `index` action in `expense_notifies_controller.rb`

```
def index
    @expense_notifies = ExpenseNotify.all.includes(:user)
end
```

This is my view `index.html.erb`

```
<% @expense_notifies.each do |expense_notify| %>
<%= expense_notify.user.first_name %> <%=expense_notify.user.last_name%>
<%end%>
```

Everytime I run `rspec spec/views/expense_notifies/index.html.erb_spec.rb`

```
Failure/Error: <%= expense_notify.user.first_name %> <%=expense_notify.user.last_name%>

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

The `expense_notify.rb` model

```
class ExpenseNotify < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

How do I get the test to pass?

Comment: it says, expense_notify's user relation is nil. try also creating users.

Comment: the user model exist and there is a user with specified ids 1 and 2.

Comment: you may be running your tests in wrong environment. i couldn't see you create users on your test. you can also check your test environment seeds.

Comment: _"there is a user with specified ids 1 and 2."_ - @suresh your error suggests the inverse. There are no users with those IDs in your test database at the time of running of Rspecs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** hardcode the IDs for assignment. You can *never* make sure that objects with a particular set of IDs exist for every run of RSpecs in your database.

Instead create `User` objects and use `user.id`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "expense_notifies/index", type: :view do
  let(:user_1) { User.create! }
  let(:user_2) { User.create! }

  before(:each) do
    assign(:expense_notifies, [
      ExpenseNotify.create!(user_id: user_1.id),
      ExpenseNotify.create!(user_id: user_2.id)
    ])
  end
end
```

See the use of [`let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) in RSpecs.

Another suggestion, you could use [`factory_bot`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) to create `User` and `ExpenseNotify` objects in test environment.